# How do I serve an entire angularJS SPA from a static express page upon authentication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, express, routes

So I built an SPA for the company I work for and it can't go online until I have incorporated authentication due to the VERY sensitive nature of the data it displays. For this reason, I am attempting to build a static express page for login as opposed to handling this in the SPA.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

1. Serve my login page.
2. Call the API route used for authentication.
3. If successful serve the SPA.
4. If unsuccessful display an appropriate error message and re-render the login page.

I have built an authentication scheme with JWTs before, so I am not worried about that part. Right now I simply want to serve my SPA with the click of a button. If I remove the routes below and go to the home page my applications loads as normal. My problem is I'm trying to route to the angular app's homepage ('/#/') and express renders the login page.

The button on my homepage makes a get request to login. I want this to redirect to the SPA I've already built. Seems like it should be simple but I can't figure out how to do it for the life of me.

```
//Login routes, success delivers angular SPA
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.jade', {
    title : "n562d", 
    strapline : "Please Log In"
  })
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#/')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are bit confused. Use express as the **REST** engine when it comes to routes. **Angular routes** will take care of the display logic and view routing on the client side.

I would suggest you to pass JSON data to front end angular and let it do the job for you. 
For example:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    title : "n562d", 
    strapline : "Please Log In"
  })
});
```

You can access the API at the endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/`
Use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) services to access the express endpoint:

example:

```
var MyResource = $resource('/');
 var myResource = new MyResource();
 myResource.$get(function(result){
   //result holds -->{title : "n562d", strapline : "Please Log In"}
   //use $location to change the uri, which is handled by Angular route config
   $location.path('/') 
 });
```

For angular routing,i would suggest you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

example:

```
function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     $stateProvider
     .state('index', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: 'app/authorization/index.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthController'
    })
     .state('login', {
      url: "/login/",
      templateUrl: 'app/authorization/login.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthController'
    })
    .state('signup',{
      url: "/signup/",
      templateUrl : 'app/authorization/signup.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthController'
    });
}
]);
```

Please note: I just named my controller as AuthController, you can replace it with name of your controller, same with views to.

Let me know if you need more detailed answer then i will update it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working based on your suggestions! I realize now what I was initially trying to do is rather useless and I've restructured the application. Now angular handles the views and forms and just sends JSON to the backend; I was perceiving a security threat that was nonexistant. I'm very new to this. Sorry that I can not upvote your response, I don't have enough reputation. :(

Comment: @awimley, it's okay, i am happy that my answer has helped you.  One more  tips,  implement [JWT ](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) for all your backend API's in order to secure your endpoints from unauthorized access.